# How to make a web grid page and use viewstate instead of re-running the query

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a web grid, pick your favorite because I really don't think it changes the answer to this question - Microsoft, Telerik, Dev Express - and I have it set to use paging.

I'm using Telerik but I'm not putting that in the tags because I don't think the problem is in the grid itself, I think it's in how I'm locating the databinding code.

I have a class that inherits from `WebConrol` and when I page the grid this code runs again, which rebinds the grid. My issue is hitting the database (and waiting) multiple unnecessary times.

I'll take an answer for ~any~ type of web data grid. I think I can translate it if necessary to my type of grid.

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Drawing

<ToolboxData("<{0}:ReportGrid runat=server></{0}:ReportGrid>")> _
<ToolboxBitmap(GetType(ReportGrid), "MyCompany.Web.UI.WebControls.ReportGrid.bmp")> _
Public Class ReportGrid
  Inherits CompositeControl

  Private _Grid As RadGrid
  Private ReadOnly Property Grid As RadGrid
    Get
      If _Grid Is Nothing Then
        _Grid = New RadGrid
        _Grid.ClientSettings.Scrolling.UseStaticHeaders = True
        '_Grid.Skin = "Black"
        _Grid.AllowFilteringByColumn = True
        _Grid.EnableAjaxSkinRendering = True
        _Grid.AllowPaging = True
        _Grid.AllowSorting = True
        _Grid.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled
        _Grid.GridLines = GridLines.Both
      End If
      Return _Grid
    End Get
  End Property

  Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
    Controls.Add(Grid)
    'If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    'This code runs on every page load
    Dim DataTable As DataTable = MyCompany.Library.Database.GetDataTable("My Connection String", "My Query")
    Grid.DataSource = DataTable
    Grid.DataBind()
    'End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Telerik user myself, I'd recommend using the RadGrid's OnNeedDataSource to handle paged data. More info on how that works here:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/simple-vs-advanced/defaultcs.aspx

If you have hundreds of thousands or millions of records to display in your grid, you'd want to look at using a custom paging solution - i.e. only pull back the records from the datasource that are required to display on that current grid page, instead of pulling in all records every time a postback occurs.

Take a look at this example on how to implement custom paging in the Telerik RadGrid:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/paging/custom-paging/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I was hoping that it could take all the data initially and just use javascipt (ajax techniques) to page. I can't believe such a popular and "big" grid can't just do that. Way back in 1998 I used an xml island and paged instantly just on the client - that was before AJAX!